# Traveling salesman (Dynamic Approach) retrieve path without losing on time complexity

Tags: c++, performance, recursion, complexity, traveling-salesman

It is difficult to find resources on above programming problem therefore I've decided to ask a question on this forum. Using memoization and dynamic programming we can obtain a code that gives \$O(2^N \cdot N)\$ time complexity. The code takes in a symmetrical adjacency matrix which is stored as the `weights` vector, and it uses the `memo` vector to cache results of subproblems.

The code only accounts for minimum weight, and it does so by applying the recursive formula and taking minimum of each recursion to construct a valid result.

Here is the code in question:

```
int TspDp::solve(int mask, int position) {
    int result = INT_MAX;

    if (mask == completedTour) {
        // return weight to starting vertex
        return weights[position][0];
    }

    if (memo[mask][position] != -1) {
        return memo[mask][position];
    }

    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < cities; ++vertex) {
        // check if vertex was not visited (bitwise check for set bit at position of: vertex)
        // or in other words skip itself and visited vertices
        if ((mask&(1<<vertex))==0) {
            // calculate new distance recursively - changing the mask (which is just bitwise addition) accordingly with increasing vertex
            int newResult = weights[position][vertex] + solve(mask|(1<<vertex), vertex);
            result = min(result,newResult);
        }
    }

    return memo[mask][position] = result;
}
```

I've tried to retrieve the path from recursion by keeping track of each subproblem's path in `paths` vector, using `temp` as a temporary path that would later become the optimal path.

And it works: I am able to retrieve correct path, although my time complexity is much worse, as I had to give up on the memoization due to not having any clue as to how I could retrieve `temp` values from `cached results`.

The time complexity of the code below is about *100-1000 times slower* than the expected one, and it was tested on matrices of size 10 and 12.

The code with path retrieval:

```
int TspDp::solveWithPath(int mask, int position) {
    int result = INT_MAX;
    int optimalPathPosition = -1;

    vector<int> paths[cities];

    if (mask == completedTour) {
        temp.clear();
        temp.push_back(position);

        // return weight to starting vertex
        return weights[position][0];
    }

    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < cities; ++vertex) {
        // check if vertex was not visited (bitwise check for set bit at position of: vertex)
        // or in other words skip itself and visited vertices
        if ((mask&(1<<vertex))==0) {
            // calculate new distance recursively - changing the mask (which is just bitwise addition) accordingly with increasing vertex
            int newResult = weights[position][vertex] + solveWithPath(mask|(1<<vertex), vertex);
            temp.push_back(position);
            paths[vertex] = temp;
            if (min(result, newResult) == newResult) {
                optimalPathPosition = vertex;
                paths[vertex] = temp;
            }
            result = min(result, newResult);
        }
    }

    temp = paths[optimalPathPosition];

    return result;
}
```

What can I do with the second code to account for memoization, and can it can run faster?